# Update the database with new component value ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, textfield, material-ui

I have a ReactJS app where I have to take the values from the components and pass it to the model and update the db.
This is my textfield component.

```
<TextField
                floatingLabelText="Decrease amount"
                floatingLabelFixed={false}
                className={styles.txtSize}
                multiLine={true}
                fullWidth={false}
                errorText={this.state.propertyConfiguration.config.forecast.numdays.errorText}
                onChange={(event) => {
                  onChangeCallback("config.forecast.numdays", event.target.value);
                }}
              />
```

So I have to write code un onChangeCallback event where I should be able to pass data like

```
{
  "type": "compset",
  "operation": "increase",
  "unit": "fixed",
  "amount": 30
}
```

So if the operation is increase then data should go in increase and if it is decrease then the data should go in decrease.
The operation is decided by which textfield the data is being added too.
I have one more field to do decrease.

Comment: By 'if the operation is increase then data should go in increase' do you mean, the data should be sorted in increasing order?

Comment: @AanchalSharma no. if the operation is increase it should be added to increase object. I have one more such object for decrease.